# Java imports simple use

Tags: java, import

I have a question, I want to import a class, and when I have imported the class. I don't want to have to re-call the imported class. For example, instead of Class.method();.
It will just simply be
method();.

Comment: You could try extending that class

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "calling" or "re-calling" a class? Classes aren't called. Are you referring to methods or constructors?

Comment: This isn't good code style for OOP

Comment: @Blobonat Agreed! What's the problem by calling `Class.method()`?

Answer (score 3):

You can so this with `import static` if `method()` is a `static` method:

```
import static com.somepackage.SomeClass.method;

// ...

// Will call SomeClass.method();
method();
```

This obviously won't work with non-static methods, because you have to specify on which object you want to call the non-static method.